# Draw Box Around Part of an NSString

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift, nstextview

I need to decorate the paragraph that encloses the current selection with a border. Here's a mockup in which the insertion point is somewhere in the second paragraph:

[image: Mockup]

Right now I'm getting the `CGRect` of the paragraph which contains the current selection point and in my `NSTextView` subclass I'm overriding `drawRect` and doing

```
var path = NSBezierPath(roundedRect: currentParagraphRect, xRadius: 4, yRadius: 4)
path.stroke()
```

This does indeed draw a box around the paragraph but it doesn't erase it so I'm left with a mess of unerased lines as the document progresses.

I'm not sure that this is the correct override point because I get the feeling `drawRect` should only be called a few times, not every single time the selection point changes, which happens a lot.

Am I on the wrong track? Should I be overriding a different drawing mechanism?

Or should I be asking the Layout Manager to create an NSTextView for each paragraph and then drawing a box around the whole view instead?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure that this is the correct override point because I get the feeling drawRect should only be called a few times, not every single time the selection point changes, which happens a lot.

`drawRect:` gets called all the time, it's a very, very popular function.  This is why you it sends the `rect` as a parameter, so you don't have to redraw the whole view every time it gets called.

If you want to keep trying to override `-drawRect:`, you need to paint over the whole rect before stroking onto of it, and you do this every time

```
self.backgroundColor.setFill()
NSBezierPath.fillRect(dirtyRect)
// draw your oval around the current paragraph 
// call super
```

Then, every time the selected paragraph changes, you need to make sure `setNeedsDisplay:` is called.